# Is it better to use the Perl DBI module or to set up a system DSN and use ODBC?

Tags: windows, perl, oracle, odbc, dbi

I am using Perl to collect data from several log files and store it into an Oracle database on the same Windows 2003 host I am running my script on. Is it better to use the Perl DBI module or to set up a system DSN and use ODBC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBI, or at least something based on DBI is the standard way of interracting with data bases in Perl. Then under DBI, you can use either a direct oracle driver (DBD::Oracle) or an ODBC driver (aptly named DBD::ODBC). So really it doesn't seem to matter much which one you use, at least not for your code.

As for a layer *above* DBI, I like [DBIx::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Simple), but there are others.

Comment: I've heard ODBC can be slower too, and I just noticed the other day the Oracle Instant Client for Windows contains a whole Perl+DBI install...